# Displaying change java

Tags: java

Im trying to take an amount of change, less than $1.00, but more than zero and display the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies that will be required to make that change. The output must be presented in a descriptive manner that resembles the English language with the following gramatical rules:

if the amount is zero, the word "no" should be used.
if the amount is 1, the unit must be singular.
if the amount is not 1, the unit must be plural.

Also, The program should catch a user mistake when entering anything under 0 or over 1 and go into a data validation loop to display the prompt and ask that the user re-enter the amount. This loop would continue until the user enters an amount less than $1.00, but more than zero.

**When I run my code I kept getting *4* repeatedly.**

**Thanks for your time! and any help is very much appreciated!**

**My code so far:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class CoinChange
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {               
           double amt; 
           int cents, quarter, dime, nickle, penny;

           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

           System.out.print("Change in Coins\n" +
                           "----------------\n\n");

           System.out.println("Enter the amount less than $1.00, but\n" +
                            "more than zero.");

           System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                    amt = keyboard.nextInt();

    // ----------------------------------------------             

           cents = (int)(amt*100 + .1);

           quarter = cents/25;
           cents %= 25;

           dime = cents/10;
           cents %= 10;

           nickle = cents/5;
           cents %= 5;

           penny = cents;

    // -----------------------------------------

           while(amt > 0 && amt <= 1)
           {

    // ----------------------------------------- 

             if(quarter == 0)
             {
                System.out.print("no ");
             }
             else
                System.out.print(quarter);
             }
             if(quarter == 1)
             {
                System.out.print("quarter");
             }
             else
             {
                System.out.print("quarters");
             }



           }           
    }
```

Comment: What were you hoping this line would do: `while(amt > 0 && amt <= 1)`?

Comment: Next question: what kinds of values do you want `amt` to be?  How did you declare `amt`?

Comment: take an amount of change, less than $1.00, but more than zero @ajb

Comment: What values of type `int` are more than zero but less than 1.00?  `int` can only hold integer values.

Comment: `amt` is the amount the user enters. I declared it as an `int` with quarters, dimes, etc. @ajb

Comment: @ajb ohh I see let me correct something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `amt` as `int` instead use `float`

```
float amt = 0.0;
int cents, quarter, dime, nickle, penny;

// Get amt from user between 0.0 and 1.0

cents = (int)amt*100;

quarter = cents/25;
cents -= quarter*25;

dime = cents/10;
cents -= dime*10;

nickel = cents/5;
cents -= nickel*5;

penny = cents;

// Then print out the numbers of each

/*
if amt = 0.91

cents = 91

quarter = 3
cents = 16

dime = 1
cents = 6

nickel = 1
cents = 1

penny = 1
*/
```

**Using Modulo %**

```
float amt = 0.0;
int cents, quarter, dime, nickle, penny;

// Get amt from user between 0.0 and 1.0

cents = (int)amt*100;

quarter = cents/25;
cents = cents % 25;

dime = cents/10;
cents = cents % 10;

nickel = cents/5;
cents %= 5;

penny = cents;

// Then print out the numbers of each
```

**Full Program**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float amt;
        int cents, quarter, dime, nickle, penny;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Change in Coins\n" + "----------------\n\n");

        System.out.println("Enter the amount less than $1.00, but\n"
                + "more than zero.");

        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");

        amt = keyboard.nextFloat();
        keyboard.close();

        cents = (int) (amt * 100);

        quarter = cents / 25;
        cents = cents % 25;

        dime = cents / 10;
        cents = cents % 10;

        nickle = cents / 5;
        cents %= 5;

        penny = cents;

        System.out.println("$" + amt + " = " + quarter + " quarters, " + dime
                + " dimes, " + nickle + " nickles and " + penny + " pennies");

    }
}
```

**Test it:** http://ideone.com/4Xq466

Comment: its says loss of precision and if i just leave a 0 it will still repeat 4 many times

Comment: @Smith Check out now.

Comment: I have to use the modulus operator to get the remaining cents its part of the specifications.

Comment: `cents %= 10` is shorthand for `cents = cents % 10` and i already have that.

Comment: @Smith Don't leave the question unclosed.

Comment: @Smith Which part isn't clear to you? What part isn't working? You want us to write whole program?

Comment: Im not saying write the whole program, Im just saying that I had already written everything for the modulo and i just edited the `float amt = 0.0;` and yet when I enter 1 or less then 1 it still repeats the output many many times like this: **4444444444444444** etc,.

Comment: This is my bad entirely i forgot too add a few more specifications

Comment: @Smith I thought, my comment `// print out numbers` will be clear enough. Why use loop and nested loop anyway>

Comment: The output must be presented in a descriptive manner that resembles the English language with the following gramatical rules:

if the amount is zero, the word "no" should be used.
if the amount is 1, the unit must be singular.
if the amount is not 1, the unit must be plural.

and the loop was also for if the entered anything over 1 and under 0 it would iterate **"Re-enter amount: "**

Comment: @Smith If I were you, I would use ternary operator for that purpose. However, you can use your own logic.

Comment: I would too but i have to follow specifications.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are entering in numbers like 1.05, 1.15, etc. If you enter that as the amt, you multiply by 100 (to get total cents) and add .1 (not sure why you did that). And then cast into an int when you really want a double. Since you cast into an int, cents / 25 will typically be 4 as, for example, 115/25 divides four times with the remainder thrown out, hence why you keep getting four as an answer.

Comment: Im trying to enter only numbers between 0 - $1.00

Comment: @Smith either way you need to cast into a double to properly divide the numbers.

Comment: He only wants ints, which is why he's multiplying by 100. He's adding 0.1 to try to make it more than zero as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. The only problem is you get stuck in a loop at the end because amt is always the original amount so it prints out the output forever.

If you want to output , for example,

quarter 
quarter 
dime 
penny 
penny

then you need to decrement the amt as you go.

edit** well... it looks weird, like you're just counting the number of quarters used. But the problem is the same. I'm not sure why you even need a loop.

Comment: Thats my bad i have not yet entered the other part. but the loop is for catching a mistake when the user enters anything above 1.00 and it should go into a data validation loop to display the prompt and ask that the user re-enter the amount. This loop would continue until the user enters an amount less than $1.00, but more than zero.

Comment: I ran your code in debug mode and it counts up the quarter nickels dimes, etc correctly. Then it just gets stuck in the loop printing out 222222222222222.... etc because there were 2 quarters when I input 0.68

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextInt()` returns an int. If you're expecting the user to enter an integer number of pennies, 1 through 99, then you should just assign it to cents. You're confusing yourself with `amt`.

Comment: Then what do i put for `amt` in this part of the code 
`cents = (int)amt*100;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use keyboard.nextDouble(). And you should use BigDecimal for monetary comparison. Try the below code:

```
   public class CoinChange {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        double amt = getValidInputFromUser();

        int remainingCents = (int) (amt * 100);         

        int quarters = remainingCents / 25;
        remainingCents %= 25;

        int dimes = remainingCents / 10;
        remainingCents %= 10;

        int nickles = remainingCents / 5;
        remainingCents %= 5;

        int pennies = remainingCents;

        System.out.println(String.format(
                    "Quarters %d, Dimes %d, Nickles %d, Cents %d", quarters,
                    dimes, nickles, pennies));      
    }


    private static double getValidInputFromUser() {
        double amt = BigDecimal.ZERO.doubleValue();
        do {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Change in Coins\n" + "----------------\n\n");
            System.out.println("Enter the amount less than $1.00, but\n"
                    + "more than zero.");
            System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
            amt = keyboard.nextDouble();
        } while (amountGreaterThanOne(amt) || amountIsZero(amt));
        return amt;
    }


    private static boolean amountIsZero(double amt) {
        return (BigDecimal.valueOf(amt).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0);
    }


    private static boolean amountGreaterThanOne(double amt) {
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(amt).compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) > 0;
    }
}
```